# Biblio import "choose file" disabled

Tags: importing-exporting

I exported a .enw file from Biblio in drupal 6 and am attempting to import it into my drupal 7 site. However on the "data import" tab, "choose file" is grayed out and disabled. What needs to be done to import the drupal 6 biblio nodes?

Answer (score 0):

I had to enable the Advanced Import module from Biblio in order to get the file to import.

https://www.drupal.org/project/biblio_advanced_import